# cannot find momd

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios5

I am using a Core Data Singleton found  at http://nachbaur.com/blog/smarter-core-data.

I have my **AP.xcdatamodeld** file with an Entity named *Customers* and *Appointments*.

The issue I'm running into is this part of the code.

```
NSString * const kDataManagerBundleName = @"AP";
NSString * const kDataManagerModelName = @"AP";
NSString * const kDataManagerSQLiteName = @"AP.sqlite";

- (NSManagedObjectModel*)objectModel {
    if (_objectModel)
        return _objectModel;

    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    if (kDataManagerBundleName) {
        NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:kDataManagerBundleName ofType:@"bundle"];
        bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:bundlePath];
    }
    NSString *modelPath = [bundle pathForResource:kDataManagerModelName ofType:@"momd"];
    NSLog(@"Path: %@",modelPath);
    _objectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:modelPath]];

    return _objectModel;
}
```

The issue is modelPath is null.

I have gone into my simulator and right clicked the .app and explored it's contents and see a folder called **AP.momd** and **Appointments.momd**. So I don't know why it would be returning *null* since the files exist.

Is my filename wrong or is the path wrong? Why is modelPath null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue. Turns out I had

```
NSString * const kDataManagerBundleName = @"AP";
```

when it should have been

```
NSString * const kDataManagerBundleName = nil;
```